# .Net Remoting Return values Discriminating between calls from different threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, remoting

I have inherited a middle tier system with some multi-Threading issues.
Two different threads, running in the same method of the same instance of a class, are making the same calls to a .Net Remoting server...

Does the proxy on the client side know how to route the return values from the remoting server to the correct thread?  Are separate client side proxies created for the calls from each thread, even though they're being called from the same instance?  Does the proxy (or proxies) on the client side know how to route the return values from the remoting server to the correct thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remoting will automatically route the returns from each call to the calling thread. You don't need to worry about it beyond your normal multi-threaded concerns. Just treat them like normal method calls.

Are you having a specific problem or are you just worried?

Comment: Component does data transfer (ETL) from one system (Source of record)  to multiple downstreeam systems, and is having general data iregularlities... Developer said than when initially developing it, he had data from the call for one downstream system ending up in a different one...